# Bank balance in my account

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planing to obtain a visit visa for the UK, my parents sponsoring for my trip, and my friend, who is in London, will bear my expenses during my short stay. Do I still have to show a big amount in my bank? And how should I show that my parents are sponsoring me?

Answer (score 3):

Both.

- They want to see the bank accounts of those who pay for your trip to decide if the money is legally earned, and if it is plausible as a *gift* to you and not a *loan*. To make this plausible, the expenses are looked at in relation to their income and savings.
- They want to see your bank accounts to gauge if you are in a stable situation at home and likely to return there, as explained by Gayot Fow in [What is the Purpose of Bank Statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105).

So they'll want to see some of your parent's bank accounts.

The relation of **income and expenditures** is much more important than the amount of **savings**. For example, if you write that you are a student, they would *expect* that you get a little money, either from your parents or from a part-time job, and that you spend most of it on a room, food, clothing, and books. That's what students do, that's what parents do, and *normal is good*.